# What is the possible reminders modulo 4 of an "odd part" of a polynomial?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Let $f(x) = 2^k \cdot m$ where $m$ is odd. The questions are

1. What are the possible values of $m \mod 4$ (1, 3 or both)? I want the algorithm which answers this question for any given polynomial.
2. Assume that both values are possible. How to find $n_1, n_2, x$ such that $f(x) \equiv 2^{n_1 - 2} \pmod{2^{n_1}}$ and $f(x) \equiv 3 \cdot 2^{n_2 - 2} \pmod{2^{n_2}}$?
3. Assume that $f(x)$ can be divisible by an arbitary large power of 2 and $f(x) \ne g(x)^2 + h(x)^2$. Is it true that both values are possible?

If there is $n$ such that $f(x)$ is never divisible by $2^n$, then it is enough to consider $f(x)$ modulo $2^{n + 2}$.

Sometimes the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\right)$ is always 1 or -1. These questions arose when I was developing an algorithm for cheking this.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Jacobi symbols are just motivation. I clarified the question.

Comment: Shall we assume x takes integer values?

Comment: @DanielAsimov Yes, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.